# how to find a view by a custom made attribute in android

Tags: android, xml

How do I get a component by referring its attribute?

```
Button attribute1 = "@+myAttributes/one"/>

//something like
Button Button1 = (Button) findViewByattribute1(R.myAttributes.one);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code.

```
Button buttonName = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButton);
```